# Tests never succeed on pyspark 3.4.0 (work OK on pyspark 3.3.2)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a project that uses pyspark. The tests have always run fine on pyspark versions prior to pyspark 3.4.0 but now fail on that version (which was released on 2023-04-13, 40 days ago as I write this).

My project is configured to use the latest available version of pyspark:

```ini
dependencies = [
  "pyspark",
  "faker"
]
```

https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/blob/c1629cee4e4b8fb0b4471f6fc2941f1b0a99a4bf/pyproject.toml#L26-L29

The tests are run using GitHub Actions. An example of the failing tests is at https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/actions/runs/4977164046, you can see there that the tests are run upon various combinations of OS & python version, they are all cancelled after running for over 5 hours
[image]

If I [pin the version of pyspark to 3.3.2](https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/commit/5fd7115d3719a7d6ef2547e8e35feb3ed76ee99f)

[image]

then the tests all succeed in ~10 minutes

[image]

https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/actions/runs/5061332947

This can be reproduced by cloning the repository and running only one test. The project uses hatch for managing environments and dependencies so you would need that installed (`pipx install hatch`/`brew install hatch`). I have reproduced the problem on python3.10.

Reproduce the problem by running these commands:

```bash
# force use of python3.10
export HATCH_PYTHON=/path/to/python3.10
git clone https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark.git
cd jstark
# following command will create a virtualenv & install all dependencies, including pyspark 3.4.0
hatch run pytest -k test_basketweeks_by_product_and_customer
```

On my machine this never completes. I need to CTRL+C to crash out of it. I consider this to be equivalent behaviour to the tests that fail in the GitHub Actions pipeline after 6 hours.

Now let's checkout the branch which pins pyspark to 3.3.2 and run the same thing (the hatch environment will get rebuilt with pyspark 3.3.2)

```bash
git checkout try-pyspark3-3-2
hatch run pytest -k test_basketweeks_by_product_and_customer
```

this time it succeeds in ~31seconds:

```bash
➜  hatch run pytest -k test_basketweeks_by_product_and_customer
============================================================================================================================= test session starts ==============================================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.10, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /private/tmp/jstark
plugins: Faker-18.9.0, cov-4.0.0
collected 79 items / 78 deselected / 1 selected

tests/test_grocery_retailer_feature_generator.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [100%]

====================================================================================================================== 1 passed, 78 deselected in 31.30s =================
```

[image]

That particular test constructs a very very complex pyspark dataframe which I suspect might be contributing to the problem, however the issue here is that it works on pyspark 3.3.2 but not on pyspark 3.4.0.

Now that I have reproduced the problem I'm wondering what to do about it. I did consider raising an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/ but thought I would come here first.

Are there any folks here that are intimately familiar with the inner workings of spark to know what might be the cause of this issue?

Comment: I have raised this at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-43972

Comment: Using Spark 3.5.0, your test passes.

Comment: indeed it does, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You're building your application against python 3.7. But from Spark 3.4, python 3.7 is deprecated, as stated in [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/index.html).

> Spark runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13, Python 3.7+, and R 3.5+. Python 3.7 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.4.0. Java 8 prior to version 8u362 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.4.0. When using the Scala API, it is necessary for applications to use the same version of Scala that Spark was compiled for. For example, when using Scala 2.13, use Spark compiled for 2.13, and compile code/applications for Scala 2.13 as well.

It is a bit misleading because on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/), python 3.7 is among the compatible version for pyspark, but I think the official documentation is more up-to-date

Comment: Thank you, that's useful to know however python3.7 isn't in the mix here. The problem is exhibited on python3.10