# Extremely slow execution in Spark 3.4.1 when computing the sum of pySpark DataFrame columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We are in the process of upgrading some spark (pySpark to be precise) jobs to Spark 3.4.1 (they are currently running on Spark 3.1.2) and we are observing some weird behavior. With Spark 3.1.2 we had some code for doing a sum of columns that was running fine, but with Spark 3.4.1, the same code is just running forever. In a nutshell, and in a very simplified way, we have a variable with a list of column names that we use for computing their sum. The actual computation is a bit more complex than that, but with just a sum we already observe the never ending execution problem, so this should be enough for this discussion. So basically, this piece of code takes ages to compute:

```
data = [{f"col{i}": i for i in range(50)} for _ in range(5)]
df_data = sql_context.createDataFrame(data)

df_data = df_data.withColumn(
    "col_sum", sum([F.col(f"col{i}") for i in range(50)])
)
df_data.show(10, False)
```

We have tested the example above for a variable number of columns and up to around 20 columns, it works fine, but already for 25 columns, the execution time is just prohibitively big for even extremely small dataframes.

The same code was working fine in 3.1.2, could anybody explain why this code seems to be so inneficient in 3.4.1? Could this be a bug in the execution plan optimizer? The behavior seems to start appearing when there are more than 23-24 columns, which made a colleague suggest that it could be related to the limit of 22 elements in a tuple in Scala 2.13, could this be the reason? Any thoughts or insights? And the most important thing, any idea why this was running fine in 3.1.2?

Regarding the code itself, we have refactored it for removing the sum of columns, but we would like to understand why this sum of columns is so inneficient, to make sure that we don't face a similar issue in the future.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using Spark 3.3.0, I don't get this issue so there is something happening in Spark version 3.4. It seems you have a similar problem than the one described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318901/tests-never-succeed-on-pyspark-3-4-0-work-ok-on-pyspark-3-3-2

Comment: Using Spark 3.5.0, I also don't get this issue

Answer (score 1):

I opened a bug on Spark (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-45745) and a developer pointed me to this other bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-45071 which seems to be the reason of the slowness. This problem should be fixed in the upcoming Spark 3.4.2.